# Casting child to parent with generics

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

```
Class a <T> {
   public T j;
}

class b:a <int> {

}
```

If this were not a generic then you could do the following:

```
a foo = new b();
```

Is there anyway to do the same with the generic case?

Is there a better method to do that?

Comment: @DavidePiras: are you sure you didn't change the meaning of the question? it was a bit ambiguous and you chose one interpretation of it.

Comment: reverted ;-) I did not see any difference except the colors...

Comment: @Dani, the code in the source is not ambiguous at all, it was simply poorly formatted for markdown. You can view the *[source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4a516b43-751c-40d6-be0d-36910e6f82a8/view-source)* of the first revision to verify for yourself. Text reformatted to follow original intent.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: oh right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the generic parameters declared in `a`:

```
class a<T>
{
    public T j;
}
```

You also need them in `b` to be able to derive from `a`:

```
class b<T> : a<T> { }
```

and then you can cast `b<T>` to `a<T>`:

```
a<int> foo = new b<int>();
```

Or you can derive from specific `a`:

```
class b : a<int> { }
```

and then cast:

```
a<int> foo = new b();
```

Comment: This isn't the case- the OP's B can be cast to `a<int>`, it doesn't need type parameters.

Comment: @ChrisShain: thats after someone else's edit, check the original.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
a<int> foo = new b();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Base<int> foo = new Derived();
}

class Base<T>
{
    public T data;
}

class Derived:Base<int>
{
}
```